# value repeats in next loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

```
function attribute_manager() {
$checkattr = $this->connection->query("SELECT * FROM attribute_grup");
while ($attrs = $checkattr->fetch_object()) {
    $id = $attrs->att_gr_id;
    $checkattrs = $this->connection->query("SELECT * FROM product_attribute WHERE att_group = $id");
    while ($values = $checkattrs->fetch_object()) {
            $valuez .= $values->att_name.', ';          
    }

    $linkz_header = '<li class="table_header">
                            <div class="options_column"><strong>Attribute Titel</strong></div> 
                            <div class="options_column">Optionen</div>
                            <div class="options_column">Werte</div>
                            </li>';
                    $linkz .= '<li>
                            <div class="options_column"><strong>'.$attrs->att_gr_name.'</strong></div> 
                            <div class="options_column">
                                <a style="color:green;" href="?seite=shop&act=edit&id='.$products->id.'">Bearbeiten</a> 
                                <a style="color:red;" href="?seite=shop&act=delete&id='.$products->id.'">LÃ¶schen</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="options_column">'.$valuez.'</div>
                            </li>';
}
return '<ul id="posts_menu">'.$linkz_header.$linkz.' </ul>';

}
}
```

This is the result, as you can see the values from FARBE join with the values for Größe: 
[image]

What is the proper way to solve this?

Comment: try `$linkz .=` with out the dot

Comment: without the dot it gives only one row from the first loop

Comment: i cant really tell what you want looped and what you don't

Comment: Before you get yourself into serious trouble, read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/). Things like `$id` have no business being in your query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the value of `$valuez` in each iteration.

```
while ($attrs = $checkattr->fetch_object()) {
    $valuez = ""; // Add this line
    $id = $attrs->att_gr_id;
```

Comment: Great this works, I dont know why I didnt think of this, maybe because it is 2:07 AM and I am so tired :/ thank you Rich I am going to accept your answer in few minutes when I will be able

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading this correctly, You just need to initialize the variable in the initial loop...

```
while ($attrs = $checkattr->fetch_object()) {
    $id = $attrs->att_gr_id;
    $valuez = "";
```

That way it clears out for each iteration.